# Flutter moor: missing libsqlite3.so

Tags: flutter, flutter-moor

I'm writing a simple Flutter app with Moor; I have created the table, database and dao, but when I launch the app it crashes with an error that the `libsqlite3.so` library can't be found.

This is my database

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:moor_ffi/moor_ffi.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
import 'package:moor/moor.dart';
import 'dart:io';

part 'word_database.g.dart';

class Words extends Table {
  IntColumn get id => integer().autoIncrement()();

  TextColumn get english => text()();

  TextColumn get korean => text()();
}

LazyDatabase _openConnection() {
  return LazyDatabase(() async {
    final dbFolder = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File(p.join(dbFolder.path, 'db.sqlite'));
    return VmDatabase(file);
  });
}

@UseMoor(tables: [Words], daos: [WordDao])
class WordDatabase extends _$WordDatabase {
  WordDatabase() : super(_openConnection());

  @override
  int get schemaVersion => 1;
}

@UseDao(tables: [Words])
class WordDao extends DatabaseAccessor<WordDatabase> with _$WordDaoMixin {
  final WordDatabase db;

  WordDao(this.db) : super(db);

  Future<List<Word>> getAllWords() => select(words).get();

  Future<List<Word>> getWordById(int id) => (select(words)
        ..limit(1)
        ..where((word) => word.id.equals(id)))
      .get();

  Stream<List<Word>> watchAllWords() => select(words).watch();

  Future<int> insertWord(Word word) => into(words).insert(word);

  Future updateWord(Word word) => update(words).replace(word);

  Future deleteWord(Word word) => delete(words).delete(word);
}
```

and this is my error

```
E/flutter (14384): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library (dlopen failed: library "/data/data/com.test.sample/lib/libsqlite3.so" not found)
E/flutter (14384): #0      _open (dart:ffi-patch/ffi_dynamic_library_patch.dart:13:55)
E/flutter (14384): #1      new DynamicLibrary.open (dart:ffi-patch/ffi_dynamic_library_patch.dart:22:12)
E/flutter (14384): #2      _defaultOpen (package:moor_ffi/src/load_library.dart:41:31)
E/flutter (14384): #3      OpenDynamicLibrary.openSqlite (package:moor_ffi/src/load_library.dart:99:12)
E/flutter (14384): #4      new _SQLiteBindings (package:moor_ffi/src/bindings/bindings.dart:121:19)
E/flutter (14384): #5      bindings (package:moor_ffi/src/bindings/bindings.dart:262:53)
E/flutter (14384): #6      new Database.open (package:moor_ffi/src/impl/database.dart:52:9)
E/flutter (14384): #7      new Database.openFile (package:moor_ffi/src/impl/database.dart:37:52)
E/flutter (14384): #8      _VmDelegate.open (package:moor_ffi/src/vm_database.dart:39:22)
E/flutter (14384): #9      DelegatedDatabase.ensureOpen.<anonymous closure> (package:moor/src/runtime/executor/helpers/engines.dart:244:22)
E/flutter (14384): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14384): #10     DelegatedDatabase.ensureOpen.<anonymous closure> (package:moor/src/runtime/executor/helpers/engines.dart)
E/flutter (14384): #11     BasicLock.synchronized (package:synchronized/src/basic_lock.dart:32:26)
E/flutter (14384): #12     DelegatedDatabase.ensureOpen (package:moor/src/runtime/executor/helpers/engines.dart:238:25)
E/flutter (14384): #13     LazyDatabase.ensureOpen.<anonymous closure> (package:moor/src/utils/lazy_database.dart:43:49)
E/flutter (14384): #14     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
E/flutter (14384): #15     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter (14384): #16     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
E/flutter (14384): #17     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)
E/flutter (14384): #18     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
E/flutter (14384): #19     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
E/flutter (14384): #20     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:556:7)
E/flutter (14384): #21     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
E/flutter (14384): #22     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter (14384): #23     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
E/flutter (14384): #24     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)
E/flutter (14384): #25     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
E/flutter (14384): #26     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
E/flutter (14384):
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 15):

after long research, my issue was resolved by adding

**sqlite3_flutter_libs**

in `pubspec.yaml`

Answer (score 6):

After some research it appears this is a regression in Flutter. To address we need to update `settings.gradle`.

Below are the original (commented out) and updated versions:

```
/*
include ':app'

def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
*/

include ':app'

def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties()
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
    pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}

plugins.each { name, path ->
    def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
    include ":$name"
    project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
```

Comment: this didn't fix the issue

Answer (score 6):

I use Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and android studio Chipmunk. I have same problem and I've tried Syahbaz [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67239865/11445944) by adding `sqlite3_flutter_libs` but I got another error (works on windows). Flutter CMake version needs higher version.

```
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/sqlite3_flutter_libs/linux/CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  CMake 3.14 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.10.2
```

My ubuntu cmake version is `3.20.0`. Yes, flutter does not use Ubuntu CMake but it's own version `3.10.2`.

Then I install `sqlite3` and `libsqlite3-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

and it works, the error was gone and I can use moor library to save data on ubuntu desktop.